# WindowServer Crash with Multiple External Monitors - macOS 12.4

Tags: display, crash

I use an external docking station that manages my USB inputs as well as 2 external monitors. This setup worked as expected for several years... However recently this has started causing my device to crash.

Has anyone experienced an issue similar to this? I greatly appreciate any insight or direction on how to possibly resolve this issue.

**The steps I take to reproduce this issue:**

1. I plug in my docking station my MacBook with multiple external monitors connected
2. This sends me to an unusual sign in page (as I'm the only individual that uses this device) that requests a username before signing in
3. After I've signed in the external monitors will not connect & I will get booted back to the sign-in screen in only a few seconds
4. Repeat ad nauseam

**Solutions attempted so far**

- If only one external monitor is connected the device does not crash
- If the second external monitor is connected via an HDMI dongle (in addition to the docking station) the device does not crash
- I have uninstalled and reinstalled the DisplayLink manager
- I have ensured that the DisplayLink "Login Screen Extension Status" is not installed

**Device Specs**

- 15" 2018 intel MacBook Pro
- 2.2 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7
- macOS 12.4

**Docking Station Specs**

- DisplayLink Manager 1.7.1
- [Plugable UD3900Z](https://plugable.com/en-ca/products/ud-3900z)

Comment: Why're you using DisplayLink?  A 2019 MBP supports two monitors natively.

Comment: I've deleted the logs you posted in the space reservered for answers. See https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4110/how-to-attach-files-that-exceed-character-count-limit-for-thread-insertion-inlin for ways to proceed in such cases.